# Possible strict aliasing violation?

Tags: c++, c++20, undefined-behavior, strict-aliasing

I was scrolling through some posts and I read about something called the strict aliasing rule. It looked awfully close to some code I've seen in a club project, relevant snippet below.

```
LibSerial::DataBuffer dataBuffer;
size_t BUFFER_SIZE = sizeof(WrappedPacket);

while(true) {
    serial_port.Read(dataBuffer, sizeof(WrappedPacket));
    uint8_t *rawDataBuffer = dataBuffer.data();

    //this part
    auto *wrappedPacket = (WrappedPacket *) rawDataBuffer;
...
```

the struct definitions are:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) TeensyData {
    int16_t adc0, adc1, adc2, adc3, adc4, adc5, adc6, adc7, adc8, adc9, adc10, adc11;
    int32_t loadCell0;
    double tc0, tc1, tc2, tc3, tc4, tc5, tc6, tc7;
} TeensyData;

typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) WrappedPacket {
    TeensyData dataPacket;
    uint16_t packetCRC;
} WrappedPacket;
```

Hopefully it's pretty obvious that I'm new to C++. So 1) is this a violation of the rule? and 2) if it is, what alternative solutions are there?

Comment: Depends on what `DataBuffer` is and what `serial_port.Read` does. But most likely a `std::launder` call is missing if you actually dereference `wrappedPacket`.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not too sure myself, but LibSerial is a separate library on a Pi, so I guess DataBuffer would be some object type inside. serial_port.Read is also a function in LibSerial, and it reads and copies the data sent to the port into dataBuffer to my understanding.

Comment: If you don't know, then assume that it is an aliasing violation. The exception to the rule requires you to carefully decide how the buffer is created and used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, it's a violation.  The rule lets you use raw byte access (`char*`, `unsigned char*`, `std::byte*`) to access other data types.  It doesn't let you use other data types to access arrays of raw bytes.

The solution is `memcpy`:

```
WrappedPacket wpkt;
std::memcpy(&wpkt, dataBuffer.data(), sizeof wpkt);
```

Comment: Depending on `DataBuffer`, `Read` and the rest of the code inbetween, they may be saved by implicit object creation since the type is trivial. Still, your solution is clearly preferred if possible.

Comment: @user17732522: Implicit object creation would result in indeterminate contents which cannot be read without causing UB.

Comment: If `serial_port.Read` internally uses `memcpy` or any other function which creates objects implicitly, then this is not an issue.

Comment: As someone who's done stuff like this a lot: I strongly recommend you explicitly deserialize data coming from an external device as it clearly is here. Neither casting nor plain memcpy are going to protect you from issues of endianness, unexpected padding, etc.

Comment: @JonReeves: `memcpy` most certainly will correct alignment (the source can be unaligned, the destination is aligned because the compiler made it so, and memcpy will transfer bytes between no problem).  It won't help with the others of course.

Comment: True @BenVoigt, throwing that in there is a little hand wavy in this context, worth striking out.

Comment: I just found out that DataBuffer is a typedef for std::vector<char> http://libserial.sourceforge.net/doxygen/class_serial_port.html#a79ebecdd332d735e749c552b1db5b74b Is this still UB? I heard that char[] can still work but I don't know if it applies to vectors

Comment: @khuang: I explained why that's no good in my first paragraph of this answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a strict aliasing violation and UB. But I wouldn't worry too much about it.

I wouldn't want to `memcpy` a big struct solely for formal correctness, in hope that the compiler optimizes it out. But I would add `std::launder` just in case<sup>1</sup>:

```
auto *wrappedPacket = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<WrappedPacket *>(rawDataBuffer));
```

Here's my reasoning:

`.Read` most probably boils down to an opaque library call, so the compiler must optimize under the assumption that it does something that makes the code legal. For example, it could apply placement-new to the provided buffer, with the right type.

If we assume that it's the case, then `std::launder` would "bless" the pointer to point to the said imaginary object, fixing the UB.

We, programmers, know that this assumption is false, but the compiler doesn't.

---

I'm not sure if C++20 implicit lifetimes relax the rules here and make `launder` unnecessary. I would keep it.

---

<sup>1</sup> `launder` doesn't fix UB here. But it does reduce the probability of it blowing up in your face.

Comment: I believe `std::launder` is often attributed abilities it doesn't have. `std::launder` requires a pointer that points to an object of the type it points to and that is within its lifetime. As far as I understand it, it does not get around cast problems and pointer arithmetic problems.

Comment: Whether `std::launder` is required will depend on how exactly `data()` obtains the pointer to the buffer (and whether that buffer has a compatible type). If it is just the pointer to the start of an `uint8_t` array, then `std::launder` is required. I would also worry about alignment because nothing seems to indicate the buffer's alignment guarantees.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I've edited the answer to make it more clear: I'm not saying that it fixes UB. I'm only saying that it makes it so that the code won't blow up in your face, as long as the compiler can't see what's inside of `.Read()`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The assumption here is that `Read` internally uses a function which implicitly creates objects (either as mandated by the standard/implementation or for practical reasons since it is opaque to the compiler). Then there is an object in its lifetime (since the type here is trivial) and `std::launder` is correct.

Comment: But it is funny that you are using "bless" to describe `launder`'s effect, when the actual function originally proposed as `std::bless` had the effect that you are attributing to the opaque library call instead.

Comment: I wouldn't particularly want an extra copy of a large structure either, but I wouldn't try to invent a way to treat a probably-unaligned bag of bytes as that structure.  Instead I'd look for a way to do I/O directly into the final correctly-typed location.  In the general case that might involve a scatter-gather call.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Programmers imagine that the Committee intended to fix long-standing holes in the language semantics, and that launder was their means of doing that, when for whatever reason the Committee decided to limit the semantics of launder without providing any reasonable means for programmers to actually accomplish what they need to do.